# To append a match efficiently in Vim :g/---/s/---/X/

Tags: vim, append

**How can you refer to the match in the command `g` in Vim?**

I would like to put X after the match without replacing the match.
For instance, in the following command without writing the `create_title` twice.

```
:g/create_title/s/create_title/X/
```

You should get

```
create_titleX
```

by running the command to

```
create_tile
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need the `g` portion of the command - the substitute will only act on matching lines.  Here's what you're looking for:

```
:%s/create_title/&X/
```

The `&` represents the entire text which was matched.

Comment: That only searches the current line.

Comment: Edited to search the whole file. My bad.

Comment: I tend to use either this or \0X, but just to add another option: `:%s/create_title\zs/X/`.  `\zs` makes the match start at that point, so nothing is replaced with X at the end of the string "create_title".

Answer (score 4):

```
:%s/\(create_title\)/\1X/g
```

works for me. (if I understand your question correctly).

Comment: I tend to prefer the `&` since it's faster to type and I don't have to modify the search pattern (better for absent-minded people). Capturing a subexpression is of course much more extensible though!