# How to Search & replace in gvim the following pattern search

Tags: vim

Hi guys need solution on this i want to replace with backslash in front of the square brackets,like this if i have `[0]` or `[9]` or any number, i want to search & replace it with `\[0\]` or `\[9\]`

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332973/regex-find-and-replace-in-vim-adding-0-to-numbers and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343979/to-append-a-match-efficiently-in-vim-g-s-x

      :%s/\([0-9]\+\)/&\\/g

Answer (score 2):

You can use this command:

```
:%s/\[\(\d\+\)\]/\\[\1\\]/g
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use that command:

```
:%s;\[\d\+\ze\];\\&\\
```